# Como extrair tipo de dados de uma unica coluna e enviar para uma nova coluna em python, pandas e numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

na minha cabeça o codigo abaixo era para separar os dados em 2 colunas...

tenho uma tabela que contem float e hora misturados na mesma coluna e precisa separar para poder fazer uma conta. Exemplo: o que é hora (10:20, 07:20 e 08:20) precisa ir para outra coluna pq ai eu faço um split e converto as horas para float, mas não ta separando>

Agradeço quem conseguir me ajudar...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    7.33,
    "10:20",
    "07:20",
    "08:25"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"tempo": data})
df['hora'] = np.where(df['tempo'].str.contains(':'), df["tempo"], 'Não identificado')
df['decimal'] = np.where(df['tempo'].str.contains('.'), df["tempo"], 'Não identificado')

print(df)

#out
```

|  | tempo | hora | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7.33 | 7.33 | 7.33 |
| 1 | 10:20 | 10:20 | 10:20 |
| 2 | 07:20 | 07:20 | 07:20 |
| 3 | 08:25 | 08:25 | 08:25 |

Comment: Para a coluna decimal, isso resolveria `df["decimal"] = pd.to_numeric(df["tempo"], errors='coerce').fillna("Não identificado")`. Mas a solução do [@imonferrari](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/201329/lmonferrari) é padrão para os dois casos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para garantir que esteja trabalhando com "str" você deve colocar astype(str), e também faltou no contains utilizar o parametro de regex = Falso.

Segue o código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    7.33,
    "10:20",
    "07:20",
    "08:25"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"tempo": data})
df['hora'] = np.where(df['tempo'].astype(str).str.contains(':', regex=False), df["tempo"], 'Não identificado')
df['decimal'] = np.where(df['tempo'].astype(str).str.contains('.', regex=False), df["tempo"], 'Não identificado')

print(df)
```

Saída:

|  | tempo | hora | decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7.33 | Não identificado | 7.33 |
| 1 | 10:20 | 10:20 | Não identificado |
| 2 | 07:20 | 07:20 | Não identificado |
| 3 | 08:25 | 08:25 | Não identificado |

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pelo apoio!